# Import CSV file with partial name in vba

Tags: vba, excel

First, let me brief scenario. I want to Import specific CSV file from the user-provided location. I am able to Import it with Fix file name.

Now, I want to Import a CSV file which changing one file name each time.
E.g.

- Newdata_Files_LMBN_124587
- Newdata_Files_LMBN_458965
- Newdata_Files_LMBN_134654
- Newdata_Files_LMBN_894354, etc...

I have written code for it, but it doesn't work

```
Sub zzandand(Optional opt As String)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim compd1, compd2 As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim path As Variant
Dim tfr1, tfr2 As String

Set path = UserForm1.TextBox1

compd1 = path & "\" & Newdata_Files_ & "*" & ".csv"

If Dir(compd1, vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then
MsgBox ("The file Newdata_Files(csv) could not be found")
    Unload UserForm1
    End
Else
Workbooks.Open (compd1)
ActiveSheet.Activate
Sheets.Copy Before:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sheets.Count)
ActiveSheet.Name = "compd2"
tfr1 = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value = UCase(tfr1)
Workbooks("compd1").Close
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Using this wildcard, only the first matching file will be found, you will need to implement a loop to get all of them. Also "It doesn't work" is very poor problem statement. Please tell us exactly what doesn't work.

Comment: Is `UserForm1` only used to retrieve the folder path?

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for looking In.

below statement is creating an issue for forming file name which I want to Import

compd1 = path & "\" & Newdata_Files_ & "*" & ".csv"

Comment: Yes, UserForm1 is used to retrieve path and Its work when we are Importing "Fix" file name

Comment: Should that be `compd1 = path & "\Newdata_Files_*.csv"` instead?  (Have you tried `Debug.Print compd1` before you run the `If Dir(compd1) Then` line?)  "It doesn't work" is hard to debug - *how* doesn't it work?*

Comment: I have tried but it's not able to find the specific file name. no, I have not tried "Debug.Print compd1", for which purpose I need to use Debug.Print compd1?

Comment: 1. Remove `Set` before `path`. `path` is not an object. 2. Obey @Chronocidal's suggestion. `Debug.Print compd1` to see if it really looks like a valid filename.  3. `Dir(compd1, vbDirectory)` returns directories. Use `Dir(compd1) ` or `Dir(compd1, vbNormal) ` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Untested:

```
Sub zzandand(Optional opt As String)

    Dim compd1 As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet, wb As Workbook
    Dim path As Variant

    path = Trim(UserForm1.TextBox1)
    If Right(path, 1) <> "\" Then path = path & "\" '<<< ensure trailing "\"

    compd1 = Dir(path & "Newdata_Files_*.csv") '<<< any matches?

    If Len(compd1) = 0 Then '<<< no need for Dir here....
        MsgBox "The file Newdata_Files(csv) could not be found"
        Unload UserForm1
    Else
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(path & compd1) '<<< use the full path!
        wb.Sheets(1).Copy _
               Before:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
        wb.Close False 'close without saving

        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
        ws.Name = "compd2"
        ws.Range("A1").Value = UCase(ws.Range("A1").Value)

    End If

End Sub
```